# How do we deal with "popularity traction" in answers?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, etiquette, not-an-answer

In [this popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) there exists an answer that basically does nothing to answer the question directly.

Instead, it is a shoutout for a specific framework and technique. Over the last year, it has accumulated 16 upvotes (and 8 downvotes) despite not explaining the issue at all. ([here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25501002/1348195)).

I feel that it is misleading to users reading the question and answers and that it only got upvotes because people passed by and said "oh! I use that framework too!" (*).

So for the actual question:

- Am I reading this right?
- If so, how do we deal with it as a community and how do I deal with future incidents in the future?

(*) to be crystal clear, I have nothing against the framework and have even been involved in it in some aspects.

Comment: The OP was about yesterday it appears. If they're not responding to comments (although the last one left was May 12th by yourself) - it might be worth try commenting with a link on the post to this meta post... Mind you - if they haven't been bothered about 8 downvotes previously... not sure if one additional one it appears to have gotten since you posted this will garner any further attention...

Comment: ... not sure there's much to be done - the question is an answer as such so doesn't really justify deletion (or at least 16 people don't think so). If it'd have been spotted and downvoted earlier in its life... maybe the OP would have thought "Okay,I've read the comments - maybe this isn't actually such a good answer as I thought"

Comment: Is this a genuine question or just an attempt to unleash the meta effect on the answer? It's pretty obvious that's going to happen anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith genuine, if you have more examples of the issue please do add them.

Comment: The answer seems completely drowned by the other far more appreciated answers. I don't really see the problem here.

Comment: @Bart It accumulated 16 upvotes in a year - so obviously people _are_ seeing it.

Comment: This just isn't a problem at all.  Q+A at SO is a pretty decent way to find a "best practice" but it generally sucks at showing how to **not** solve a problem.  The more cargo-cultish the approach, the more it is appropriate to include it and starkly offset it from the favorited solution.